# Сравнение хешей 5-значных числовых кодов подтверждения

Tags: android, безопасность

Заметили у себя такую уязвимость. 
Можно узнать хеш кода подтверждения, который приходит в приложение Android и дальше легко подобрать его, просто перебирая хеши от кода 10000  и до кода 99999, пока не совпадет. Тем самым регистрируясь, злоумышленник может указать почту, которая ему не принадлежит.

Как такое можно исправить при этом оставив структуру 5-значного кода?

Comment: Предлагаю делать еще уникальную сессию и инвалидировать ее после 3 неудачных подборов

Comment: @SergeMarkov А если злоумышленник вытащит hash конкретно из android приложения при этом подбирая у себя на компьютере?

Comment: Есть специалзированные решения для усложнения эмуляции и анализа приложений (проверяют на целостность, рут, зиготы и  много чего еще). Достаточно прочно защищать от перебора сессий через FCM token, получить его достаточно сложно, это надежный канал для передачи сессионного ключа. Но в целом - как минимум любую интеракцию с сервисом на сервере делать через уникальные сессии, которые уже можно уникально отслеживать по активности.

Comment: А зачем у Вас что-то приходит в приложение - код подтверждения почты должен отправляться на саму почту - если она юзеру не принадлежит, то и код он не увидит. Далее юзер вводит код и приложение отправляет его на сервер, где он и проверяется без доступа любопытных глаз.